# How to stop ads to open in my Webview of Android App?

Tags: android, webview, ads

I am developing a mobile app. On some options I am redirecting the user to different websites like http://m.moneycontrol.com/ , http://www.redbus.com/ etc.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        WebView mainWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.mainWebView);
        mainWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyCustomWebViewClient());
        mainWebView.loadUrl("http://www.m.moneycontrol.com/");
    //  mainWebView.setScrollBarStyle(MainActivity.this.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);

        WebSettings webSettings = mainWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
         mainWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
               public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading (WebView view, String url){
                   //True if the host application wants to leave the current WebView and handle the url itself, otherwise return false.
                   return true;
               }
             });
    }

    private class MyCustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
```

When I tested the app on some phones. On 2-3 phones the webview started redirecting to different sites and started opening affiliate ads to install antivirus etc.

Please Suggest me solution to stop these ads.

Answer (score 2):

Change the useragent string of the WebView to that of IE or desktop Firefox. The websites will show the regular version of the site and hopefully the ads won't be there.

```
webview.getSettings().setUserAgentString(
       "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:13.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12");
```

Answer (score 0):

The general recommendation is not to open in your app's WebView any sites that you don't control. Instead of doing that, just launch the system browser:

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.m.moneycontrol.com/")));
```